# Why crontab can't executed on time

Tags: php, linux, cron

Hi is anybody know why the crontab could not execute on time? It delayed at least 10 seconds. It is aws EC2 Instance.

```
shell>uname -a    
shell>Linux srv-796-db1 3.14.20-20.44.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Mon Oct 6 22:52:46 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux #Server Info


awk '{split($3,a,":"); if (a[3] > 10) {print;}}' /var/log/cron | head -50
Jan 11 22:30:13 srv-796-db1 CROND[12017]: (root) CMD (sleep 20; /usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:30:13 srv-796-db1 CROND[12019]: (root) CMD (sleep 10; /usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:30:13 srv-796-db1 CROND[12021]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:30:13 srv-796-db1 CROND[12024]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:30:13 srv-796-db1 CROND[12026]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:30:13 srv-796-db1 CROND[12030]: (root) CMD (sleep 40; /usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:30:13 srv-796-db1 CROND[12032]: (root) CMD (sleep 30; /usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:30:13 srv-796-db1 CROND[12034]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:30:13 srv-796-db1 CROND[12037]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:30:13 srv-796-db1 CROND[12041]: (root) CMD (sleep 20; /usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:30:13 srv-796-db1 CROND[12045]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:30:14 srv-796-db1 CROND[12048]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:30:14 srv-796-db1 CROND[12052]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jan 11 22:40:11 srv-796-db1 CROND[18845]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:40:11 srv-796-db1 CROND[18848]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:40:11 srv-796-db1 CROND[18849]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:40:11 srv-796-db1 CROND[18854]: (root) CMD (/usr/lib64/sa/sa1 1 1)
Jan 11 22:40:11 srv-796-db1 CROND[18855]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
Jan 11 22:40:11 srv-796-db1 CROND[18858]: (root) CMD (/usr/bin/php -f #different php script here >/dev/null 2>&1)
```

Any idea???

Comment: Does cron guarantee its tasks will run exactly at `00` seconds?

Comment: No, cron did not guarantee its tasks will run exactly at 00 second. But on other Server, it usually take 1 seconds to execute all of them. In aws, it is dynamic..Have no idea why and what is root cause.

Comment: So are they the same implementations of cron? And the same versions?

Comment: How to check "implementations" and versions??

Comment: It depends on operating systems you run. Use the package manager they provide.

Comment: @_@ I am new to linux. Could you explain it more details thanks.

Comment: Refer this [1]:http://serverfault.com/questions/449651/why-is-my-crontab-not-working-and-how-can-i-troubleshoot-it

Answer (score 0):

Just Want to close this question..
Cronjob is not guarantee it tasks will run exactly on time.
However, before starting a task, it will check last task status. If last task was not finish, it will delay the process..
On the other hands, many factors...such as "open files limit", "os time" ...